# What is the difference between using R microbenchmark and system.time?

Tags: r, performance, microbenchmark

I would like to understand the difference between R's microbenchmark and system.time() ?  How do they internally measure function execution time  ?

Comment: `?microbenchmark` gives pretty good detail of how it measures runtimes. What specifically do you want to know?

Comment: This might be of interest, from Radford Neal's blog: [Inaccurate results from microbenchmark](https://radfordneal.wordpress.com/2014/02/02/inaccurate-results-from-microbenchmark/)

Comment: `microbenchmark` is based on repeated iterations. `system.time` is the time for a single run.

Comment: @thelatemail The blog post that you linked to referred to the lack of a mean in the results from microbenchmark (to loosely paraphrase: if you don't care about garbage collection or other occasional overhead time then the median is better; if you do care then the mean is better). The function has been updated since then so that it returns both measures, so there is no longer a problem.

Answer (score 0):

In both cases, the run-times are calculated using operating system facilities, so
how the run-times are calculated is OS-dependent.

As described in the Details section of [`?system.time`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/system.time):

> system.time calls the function proc.time, evaluates expr, and then
>   calls proc.time once more, returning the difference between the two
>   proc.time calls.

[`proc.time`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/proc.time) is primitive, and the C code is in [`src/main/times.c`](http://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/main/times.c).  Comments in that file state:

> proc.time() uses currentTime() for elapsed time, and getrusage, then
>   times for CPU times on a Unix-alike, GetProcessTimes on Windows.

---

From the Note section of the [`?microbenchmark`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/microbenchmark/docs/microbenchmark) page:

> Depending on the underlying operating system, different methods are
>   used for timing. On Windows the QueryPerformanceCounter interface is
>   used to measure the time passed. For Linux the clock_gettime API is
>   used and on Solaris the gethrtime function. Finally on MacOS X the,
>   undocumented, mach_absolute_time function is used to avoid a
>   dependency on the CoreServices Framework.

I can't find the microbenchmark repository, so you'll have to download the source to see the exact details, but the timing is done by `do_microtiming` in `src/nanotimer.c`, which calls an OS-dependent version of `get_nanotime`, in `src/nanotimer_nanotimer_gettime.h`/`src/nanotimer_nanotimer_macosx.h`/`src/nanotimer_nanotimer_rtposix.h`/`src/nanotimer_nanotimer_windows.h`.