# What is the fastest way to get a vector of sorted unique values from a data.table?

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36949148/3817004) to this [question (Unique sorted rows single column from R data.table)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36936613/unique-sorted-rows-single-column-from-r-data-table%20Unique%20sorted%20rows%20single%20column%20from%20R%20data.table) suggested three different ways to get a vector of sorted unique values from a `data.table`:

```
# 1
sort(salesdt[, unique(company)])
#2 
sort(unique(salesdt$company))
#3
salesdt[order(company), unique(company)]
```

Another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36951561/3817004) suggested other sort options than lexicographical order:

```
salesdt[, .N, by = company][order(-N), company]
salesdt[, sum(sales), by = company][order(-V1), company]
```

The `data.table` was created by

```
library(data.table)
company <- c("A", "S", "W", "L", "T", "T", "W", "A", "T", "W")
item <- c("Thingy", "Thingy", "Widget", "Thingy", "Grommit", 
          "Thingy", "Grommit", "Thingy", "Widget", "Thingy")
sales <- c(120, 140, 160, 180, 200, 120, 140, 160, 180, 200)
salesdt <- data.table(company,item,sales)
```

As always, if different options are available to choose from I started to wonder what the best solution would be, in particular if the `data.table` would be much larger. I have searched a bit on SO but haven't found a particular answer so far.

Comment: You can time the code by using:
`ptm <- proc.time()`
`your code`
`proc.time() - ptm`
and hence you will find what is the fastest.
(mind those are 3 lines of code, the comment shows it as one ... refer to http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/timing_code.htm for more info).

Comment: @Gracos Thank you for your suggestion. Here, the `microbenchmark` package is the better choice as it allows  for benchmarking several expressions in one step.

Comment: You are right. `proc.time()` is just a simpler alternative.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For benchmarking, a larger `data.table` is created with 1.000.000 rows:

```
n <- 1e6
set.seed(1234) # to reproduce the data
salesdt <- data.table(company = sample(company, n, TRUE), 
                      item = sample(item, n, TRUE), 
                      sales = sample(sales, n, TRUE))
```

For the sake of completeness also the variants

```
# 4
unique(sort(salesdt$company))
# 5
unique(salesdt[,sort(company)])
```

will be benchmarked although it seems to be obvious that sorting unique values should be faster than the other way around.

In addition, two other sort options from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36951561/3817004) are included:

```
# 6
salesdt[, .N, by = company][order(-N), company]
# 7
salesdt[, sum(sales), by = company][order(-V1), company]
```

**Edit:** Following from Frank's comment, I've included his suggestion:

```
# 8
salesdt[,logical(1), keyby = company]$company
```

### Benchmarking, no key set

Benchmarking is done with help of the `microbenchmark` package:

```
timings <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  sort(salesdt[, unique(company)]),
  sort(unique(salesdt$company)),
  salesdt[order(company), unique(company)],
  unique(sort(salesdt$company)),
  unique(salesdt[,sort(company)]),
  salesdt[, .N, by = company][order(-N), company],
  salesdt[, sum(sales), by = company][order(-V1), company],
  salesdt[,logical(1), keyby = company]$company
)
```

The timings are displayed with

```
ggplot2::autoplot(timings)
```

Please, note the *reverse* order in the chart (#1 at bottom, #8 at top).

[image]

As expected, variants #4 and #5 (unique after sort) are pretty slow. **Edit:** #8 is the fastest which confirms Frank's comment.

A bit of surprise to me was variant #3. Despite `data.table`'s fast radix sort it is less efficient than #1 and #2. It seems to sort first and then to extract the unique values.

### Benchmarking, data.table keyed by `company`

Motivated by this observation I repeated the benchmark with the `data.table` keyed by `company`.

```
setkeyv(salesdt, "company")
```

The timings show (please not the *change in scale* of the time axis) that #4 and #5 have been accelerated dramatically by keying. They are even faster than #3. *Note that timings for variant #8 are included in the next section.*

[image]

### Benchmarking, keyed with a bit of tuning

Variant #3 still includes `order(company)` which isn't necessary if already keyed by `company`. So, I removed the unnecessary calls to `order` and `sort` from #3 and #5:

```
timings <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  sort(salesdt[, unique(company)]),
  sort(unique(salesdt$company)),
  salesdt[, unique(company)],
  unique(salesdt$company),
  unique(salesdt[, company]),
  salesdt[, .N, by = company][order(-N), company],
  salesdt[, sum(sales), by = company][order(-V1), company],
  salesdt[,logical(1), keyby = company]$company
)
```

The timings now show variants #1 to #4 on the same level. **Edit:** Again, #8 (Frank's solution) is the fastests.

[image]

**Caveat**: The benchmarking is based on the original data which only includes 5 different letters as company names. It is likely that the result will look differently with a larger number of distinct company names. The results have been obtained with `data.table v.1.9.7`.

Comment: Huh, why are you sometimes taking `.N` or summing `sales`, which are totally unnecessary for finding the distinct values of `company`? The only reasonable comparison would be `timings <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  salesdt[,logical(1), keyby=company]$company,
  sort(unique(salesdt$company))
); ggplot2::autoplot(timings)`

Comment: Because it is not only about getting distinct values. There are other sorting options than ordering the company names alphabetically. May be, the reasoning behind this becomes clearer from http://stackoverflow.com/a/36951561/3817004.

Comment: Ok, but (1) none of that comes up in your question here, which only pertains to the two things in my benchmark; (2) comparisons between lexicographic sorting and sorting based on aggregates like counts and sums make no sense, since obviously it takes longer when you have to compute those aggregates; and (3) is there really a question of how best to sort by counts/.N or sums? You only show one way of doing this and I think it probably is the best.... I suppose you could also `tapply`, `sort` and extract names, though that only makes sense because `company` happens to be a string.

Comment: Anyway, regarding the question posed here, you are missing `salesdt[,logical(1), keyby=company]$company`, which is fastest on my computer for your example. You can use any other length-one vector instead of `logical(1)`.

Comment: @Frank Thank you for your suggestion. I have repeated the benchmarks including your code. And - you're right!

Comment: @Frank May I suggest that you post your solution as answer to the original [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36936613/unique-sorted-rows-single-column-from-r-data-table)?

Comment: You can strip out all of the stuff from `[.data.table` to increase the speed: `v = salesdt$company; tmp = data.table:::forderv(v, sort = FALSE, retGrp = TRUE); sort(v[tmp[attr(tmp, 'starts')]])`. And you can push it further by stripping out things from `forderv` as well. And then you'll hopefully realize that the speed increase you're seeing is mostly useless unless you're running this computation in a very big loop. Most of these methods will give very similar times for large data and a "times" argument of 2-3. Millisecond benchmarks are mostly useless.

Comment: @Frank I can't put your idea into practice. How should I rephrase your example: `unique(df@myvariable)`? I tried: `df[,logical(1), keyby = myvariable]$myvariable` and I get error: Error in `[.data.frame`(df, , logical(1), keyby = myvariable) : unused argument (keyby = myvariable)`

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin Not sure I follow. Your first piece of code should have $ instead of @, I think

Comment: @Frank It was only a typo in my comment. I present problem in a separate question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67076995/1903793

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could do the following:

```
library(data.table)
n <- 1e6
salesdt <- data.table(company = sample(company, n, TRUE), 
                      item = sample(item, n, TRUE), 
                      sales = sample(sales, n, TRUE))

ptm <- proc.time() 
sort(salesdt[, unique(company)])
proc.time() - ptm

ptm <- proc.time() 
sort(unique(salesdt$company))
proc.time() - ptm

ptm <- proc.time() 
salesdt[order(company), unique(company)]
proc.time() - ptm
```

Information provided by `proc.time` is not as thorough as `microbenchmark`, but it is simpler.

Output for the above is:

```
sort(salesdt[, unique(company)])
user  system elapsed 
0.05    0.02    0.06 

sort(unique(salesdt$company))
user  system elapsed 
0.01    0.01    0.03 

salesdt[order(company), unique(company)]
user  system elapsed 
0.03    0.02    0.05
```

Where user time relates to code execution, system time to CPU, and elapsed time is the difference since starting the stopwatch (and will be equal to the sum of user and system times if code run altogether). (taken from http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/timing_code.htm)

Comment: Thank you very much for repeating the benchmarks with `proc.time`. Concerning the use of `microbenchmark` I'm following the advice of Hadly Wickham from his book [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Performance.html#microbenchmarking). There is also a good explanation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28575697/what-is-the-difference-between-using-r-microbenchmark-and-system-time) on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Using `kit::funique` or `collapse::funique` might be a fast way to *get a vector of sorted unique values*.

Also it should be considered *how many treads* are used. Using one core in data.table:

```
setDTthreads(1)
bench::mark(
dt = x[,logical(1), keyby = company]$company,
base = sort(unique(x$company)),
collapse = collapse::funique(x$company, TRUE),
kit = sort(kit::funique(x$company)))
#  expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time
#  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm>
#1 dt          130.4ms  141.5ms      7.17   49.63MB     2.39     3     1      419ms
#2 base        170.1ms  170.1ms      5.88  166.15MB    17.6      1     3      170ms
#3 collapse     51.8ms     52ms     19.1     2.49KB     0       10     0      524ms
#4 kit          17.6ms   17.8ms     56.0         0B     0       28     0      500ms
```

Using four cores in data.table:

```
setDTthreads(4)
bench::mark(
dt = x[,logical(1), keyby = company]$company,
base = sort(unique(x$company)),
collapse = collapse::funique(x$company, TRUE),
kit = sort(kit::funique(x$company)))
#  expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time
#  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm>
#1 dt           50.2ms   51.1ms     18.9    49.63MB     3.78    10     2      529ms
#2 base        147.1ms  161.3ms      6.26  166.15MB     6.26     4     4      639ms
#3 collapse     51.8ms   52.5ms     19.1     2.49KB     0       10     0      524ms
#4 kit          17.7ms   17.8ms     55.9         0B     0       28     0      501ms
```

When using `system.time` the time used by each core is summed up:

```
setDTthreads(1)
system.time(x[,logical(1), keyby = company]$company)
#       User      System verstrichen 
#      0.122       0.004       0.126 

setDTthreads(4)
system.time(x[,logical(1), keyby = company]$company)
#       User      System verstrichen 
#      0.150       0.028       0.052 

system.time(collapse::funique(x$company))
#       User      System verstrichen 
#      0.053       0.000       0.053 

system.time(kit::funique(x$company))
#       User      System verstrichen 
#      0.018       0.000       0.018
```

When using a key also the *time to create the key* should be considered:

```
system.time(setkeyv(x, "company"))
#       User      System verstrichen 
#      0.241       0.012       0.253
```

It looks like `kit::funique` is currently the fastest followed by `collapse::funique`. Using one thread `base::unique` is a little bit slower than using `data.table`.

Data and libraries:

```
set.seed(42)
n <- 1e7
company <- c("A", "S", "W", "L", "T", "T", "W", "A", "T", "W")
item <- c("Thingy", "Thingy", "Widget", "Thingy", "Grommit", 
          "Thingy", "Grommit", "Thingy", "Widget", "Thingy")
sales <- c(120, 140, 160, 180, 200, 120, 140, 160, 180, 200)

library(data.table)
x <- data.table(company = sample(company, n, TRUE), 
                      item = sample(item, n, TRUE), 
                sales = sample(sales, n, TRUE))
```